# Undo half-done database restore

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a database backup file(plain sql) containing a large number of tables and functions.
I was planning to restore it on a database in a different machine:

```
#\i backup.sql
```

But I forgot to connect to the target database first (`#\c myDB`).
I pressed Ctrl+C and the operation stopped in the middle.
Now I have a large number of tables and function... stored in the default `postgres` database.
Is there anyway to undo these changes other than manually cleaning them up one by one?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following if you don't care about what you have in the public schema of the (default) postgres database:

```
DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA public;
```